# Make missing data in choropleth map a different color

Tags: r, plotly, choropleth

R plotly choropleth map. I want to make missing data/areas some other color. Greenland is not in the dataframe at all and Russia has some NAs. There is other data missing here and there too.

```
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly(type = "choropleth", 
           locations = data$country, 
           locationmode = "country names", 
           colorscale = "RdBu",
           reversescale = TRUE,
           z = data$change) %>% 
  layout(title = "Change (%)", 
     geo = list(scope = "world")) %>% 
  colorbar(title = "Change (%)", limits = c(-20, 20))

fig
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### R Plotly Choropleth Map - Forest Coverage Change (%) 1990 to 2015

Okay, mostly sorted. It would be nice if the legend indicated the dark grey areas are missing data.

```r
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly(type = "choropleth", 
           locations = fcp_p_df$country, 
           locationmode = "country names", 
           colorscale = "RdBu",
           reversescale = TRUE,
           z = fcp_p_df$change) %>% 
  layout(title = "Forest Coverage Change (%) 1990 to 2015", 
     geo = list(scope = "world", 
        showocean = TRUE, 
        oceancolor="lightblue", 
        showland = TRUE, 
        landcolor = "gray")) %>% 
  colorbar(title = "Change (%)", limits = c(-20, 20))

fig
```

[image: map with colors added]
[R Figure Reference: layout.geo](https://plotly.com/r/reference/layout/geo/)